# Is it possible to see a user's achievements through the Battle.net web interface?

Tags: achievements, battle.net

... or any other interface that would not require to log into a Battle.net game (World of Warcraft, Starcraft 2, Diablo 3) ?  I can't seem to find it by logging in [Battle.net](http://eu.battle.net/), but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: If that can clarify the question in any way, I'm looking for a "Steam-like" user achievements page.

Comment: pretty sure that was/is possible for Starcraft 2, so I bet they are going to add it later, as of now, I don't think something like that exists yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, but Blizzard will be adding a Diablo3 web API 'soon'

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5271598804