# Is there a way to check if my friend is playing Diablo 3 outside of the game?

Tags: diablo-iii

How can I check outside of the game if my friend is playing?

Is there one page that I can search for his battletag/email and check it?

I hate to enter the game every time I want to check if my friends are playing, every time. Any faster/simple way?

Thanks :D

Comment: This used to be possible with Battle.net 1.0 (ie Diablo 2): chat clients could connect to bnet. With the latest round of games it's not supported. I think Blizzard would rather have you immersed in their blockbuster game worlds than using a chat client to talk to your friends. ;)

Comment: Maybe that the system evocated [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69249/is-it-possible-to-see-a-users-achievements-through-the-battle-net-web-interface) will bring back this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could ask your friends to add Diablo 3 to Steam or a similar tracking program(Xfire) so you can easily see when they are online, but Blizzard has no official way of seeing if a friend is online outside of the game.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way how you could actually check if your friend is online on Diablo 3 when you aren't online - you're supposed to be able to play together with your friend - or at least invite/chat while you are online in Diablo 3.

Besides, what are you doing checking up on your friend if he's playing (or not) Diablo 3 when you aren't playing? Is he grinding faster than you? In that case, that's pretty much illegal and you should be on Diablo 3 24/7 to beat his farming skillz.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check using just the web.

You could presumably start up and log into your World of Warcraft or Starcraft 2 accounts, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

You can also just log into Diablo 3, and change to Windowed mode, and make the window as small as possible (800x600 i think).  It uses far less CPU when it's no in focus or minimized.

Comment: I still stand by my option of monitoring your friend 24/7.